IonCube Loader Installed but Not Activating on My Server
I've been trying to install IonCube Loader on my server, but after following the installation steps and confirming that the extension is installed, it still doesn't seem to activate correctly.
Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Downloaded and installed the correct version of IonCube Loader for my PHP version.
Updated the php.ini file to include the correct IonCube Loader path.
Restarted my web server (Apache/Nginx) after the installation.
Ran php -v or phpinfo() to check if the extension is loaded, but it's still not showing up as active.

What am I missing, or what could be preventing the extension from loading correctly? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!
